# web scrape in another currency (several options)

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

I have a problem with **scraping** values in different currencies. For example, the following website gives info about the costs of the project in US dollars, and I can scrape it: https://indiainvestmentgrid.gov.in/opportunities/project/21117. However, there is also a possibility of choosing the currency of costs (in the top-right corner), and I want to **scrape** this info in IND. Do you have any suggestions on how can I access it? Maybe it is possible to do somehow with RSelenium?

```
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)

url <- read_html("https://indiainvestmentgrid.gov.in/opportunities/project/21117")

project_total_cost <- url %>% 
  html_nodes(".total-cost-value") %>%
  html_text()
project_total_cost 
"USD 387.24 mn"
```

Comment: Going through dropdown menus is possible, but expensive - its going to take roughly 3 seconds per page to get it reliably. In this case I think you are better off scraping using `rvest`, as you are doing now, and convert it using an exchange rate, or if you insist on using `RSelenium`, to set the value to IND once, then all subsequent pages you open in that session should be displayed using IND.

Comment: Got it, I was wondering whether it is possible to make it somehow automatically, maybe you can describe briefly how can I go through the dropdown menu (even if it is costly)?

Comment: Find the css or selector of each stage of the dropdown menu, then click on it. I.e.  `remDr$findElement("css selector", "#select_country")`> `webElem$clickElement()` > `remDr$findElement(...)` etc. https://coderedirect.com/questions/238345/how-to-select-dropdown-box-using-rselenium There are some samples of how it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

As said Donald in the comments you could use RSelenium library.

Below an example.

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
# it starts selenium
rD <- RSelenium::rsDriver(browser = "firefox", check = FALSE)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
url<-"https://indiainvestmentgrid.gov.in/opportunities/project/21117"
remDr$navigate(url)

# it activates the menu list
remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', value = "#select_country")$clickElement()

# Japan currency
remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', value = ".flagstrap-jp")$clickElement()
# Indian currency
remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', value = ".flagstrap-in")$clickElement()
# US currency
remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', value = ".flagstrap-us")$clickElement()
# EU currency
remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', value = ".flagstrap-eu")$clickElement()
# UK currency
remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', value = ".flagstrap-gb")$clickElement()
# AU currency
remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', value = ".flagstrap-au")$clickElement()
# CN currency
remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', value = ".flagstrap-cn")$clickElement()

# Here you extract the html code 
url<-read_html(unlist(remDr$getPageSource()))

# Your code
project_total_cost <- url  %>% 
  html_nodes(".total-cost-value") %>%
  html_text()
project_total_cost
```